Strange Brackets in String Writing
I was arranging a piece and was wondering what these four notes inside a bracket on the Violin part mean. I'm not a string player, but I was assuming something weird, like retuning the strings, but that would be odd and unnecessary. It could be finger positioning, but I don't know, so could somebody help?


Does the following measure start with the top G note?

please give a larger picture showing some of the following notes. it seems almost certain that these are instructions about fingering, to play the given notes in first position, one per string, and therefore likely that the next note is a G, but it would be nice to see that next note. And I’m a bit unclear on exactly what is meant by “pizz” so close to “a punta d’arco”; is this the start of an actually pizzicato section within a broader arco section? or does it somehow apply just to these notes?

It's an indication to play each note of the figure that follows on a separate string -- in other words, as an arpeggiated quadruple stop -- rather than to play, for example, the first two notes on the G string.
